# Merging 2 arrays by keys

Tags: php, arrays

There are 2 arrays, the reason for 2 arrays is because of 2 drop down from form post.

```
array1
1 => 878
2 => 983
3 => 717

array2
1 => 10
2 => 15
3 => 12
```

I have to loop 2 arrays and get where the keys matched and combine them into an array.

```
878 => 10
983 => 15
717 => 12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).  try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3cc3609829a1f0a33ddaf9745cb2df666161dd4e)

```
$combined = array_combine(array_values($array1),array_values($array2));
```

Comment: Limitation of array_combine is :- items in both array should be equal other wise it will return false value.