# How to combine two array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array $a and $b

```
Array
(
  [0] => 230
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 71
)

Array
(
  [0] => 1500
  [1] => 3500
  [2] => 5000
)
```

I want an array which will look like

```
Array
(
  [230] => 1500
  [2]   => 3500
  [71]  => 5000
)
```

How is it possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: Literally "php combine array" in any search engine would have done it...

Comment: Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076259/merging-2-arrays-by-keys/35076311#35076311).  which i already answered.

Answer (score 3):

The actual question should have led you to the answer. The way to combine two arrays is by using the [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.

Update: here is a code sample http://codepad.org/6r5DzCmc

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_combine`.

```
array_combine($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

try http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
$a = array(230, 2, 71);
$b = array(1500, 3500, 5000);

print_r(array_combine($a, $b));
```